# How to skip 'Set up windows' screen when doing unattended install of Server 2008

Tags: windows, templates, cloud, windows-server-2008-r2, imaging

I've set up an template of Windows 2008 R2 Standard for use in a cloud environment. 
The template includes a unattend.xml file in c:\windows\system32\sysprep, which tells it to skip the EULA and autologin to windows.

The image is successfully sysprepped and captured and i can deploy from it fine, the EULA doesnt appear either, however instead of autologging in, i'm presented with the 'Set up windows' screen, as seen here:

http://www.x85.co.uk/setupwindows.jpg

It seems that this is stopping my autologin, which i need to happen because theres a vb.net program set to runonce on first boot which finishes setting up all the customization for the cloud server.

Does anybody know how i can get this screen to be skipped or answered silently or whatever?

many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In AIK add windows shell setup to OOBE pass. Expand shell setup and go into OOBE. There is a HIDEEULAPage option. Make it true and it will skip all the nonsense you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Just Quickly, if i may,

I realize you want the quick answer, But.. Maybe this will be a long term solution for you.

You have obviously successfully set up an Answer File, Most techies and engineer's can do this without any issues,

Have you explored Windows A.I.K. ?

i find most techies don't even know it exists

You have tonnes of option and this will certainly fix your issue, not just for now

but for all your future issues

You can literally customize almost anything in Windows , with this Tool

Have a look and see what you think

[WINDOWS A.I.K](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=5753)

Comment: I have indeed - well to the point of following the guide from cloudstack on using the AIK to generate an answerfile.
I didnt explore the additional features, but i shall go back and do so.

I noticed that since i added the unattend.xml it takes longer to process the "setup is perparing your computer for first use" phase, so it is seemingly doing stuff, I must just have it wrong somewhere. Hopefully exploring the AIK further will yield an answer :)

Comment: Exactly, I once had a job where the company wanted to do a similiar thing with customizations like.. you can't even imagine, (stuff that makes you say.. That's impossible, you can't do that) it took me about 6 weeks to read through the AIK Manual AND UNDERSTAND IT ALL, but AIK can do pretty much anything you want, You just need to take time and research it, YES Your right, using the Wizard to make and Answer file is easy, but that just has the basic options, You also have syntax you can enter manually for advanced functions and customizations

Comment: Research at this location      {http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749082%28v=ws.10%29.aspx}  GOOD LUCK  it just takes time and patience and a lot of testing and rebooting to see the physical changes that take effect after certain things have been added to the answer file, it's really cool stuff and a great education,  But does take a while (i can't just give you the answer here , it would take too long)  I"m happy to help you in any way, if you need it. Good Luck mate